# Can steering be electrically controlled?

Tags: power-steering, steering, can-bus

Please see this: http://www.bloomberg.com/features/2015-george-hotz-self-driving-car/

George Hotz claimed he used CAN to control the car by software. I can understand that accelerating and braking can be electrically controlled as cruise control is using this. But is a stock Honda Acura ILX built to have steering also electrically controlled?

Comment: What year of Honda/Acura? You talking new?

Comment: According to the Bloomberg article, 2016.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about motor vehicle maintenance or repair, and therefore off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today, we don't only have cruise control. We also have cars which can park the car automatically in a parking spot. The driver just sits there and monitors the car, may be, he is responsible for gas and brake, but the car actuates the steering wheel.

So, you just need to know how to use this for your own projects.

Answer (score -1):

The only possible solution for cars which aren't even remotely autonomous off-the-shelf, is to have the actuators.